# Hypothesis testing: Average weight of caviar

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

A caviar producing company packs its product in containers. They claim that the average weight of the caviar in the containers is **1** kilogram. They sell each container for **8,000** CAD. We had a budget of approximately **90,000** CAD. So, we could buy 11 of the containers and weighted the caviar in each. Here are the results in Kilograms:

**0.89, 1.01, 1.00, 0.90, 0.90, 0.91, 0.91, 0.89, 0.95, 1.00, 0.96**.

If we assume that the weights are normally distributed, is there suﬃcient evidence for us to believe that the actual average weight of caviar in the containers is less than what the producer claims it is. Use the critical value approach with **α = 0.05**.

My work:

**H0: μ = 1** and **Ha: μ < 1**. I then found the mean of the results, **x̄ = 10.32/11 = 0.9382**, along with the standard deviation: **0.0475**.

Using this, I found the test statistic: **t=(0.9382-1)/[0.0475/sqrt(11)] = -0.0618/0.0143 = -4.3217** and then the critical value: **t(n-1),α = t10,0.05 = 1.812**.

**-4.3217 < -1.812** is true, so therefore H0 should not be rejected, there is enough evidence for us to believe that the actual average weight of caviar in the containers is less than what the producer claims it is.

I'm not sure if I completed the problem properly, any help/guidance is great, thanks!

Comment: How did you calculate the (estimated) standard deviation ? The formula is $\hat \sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see my mistake there now, I recalculated using the formula you provided and got 0.0475!

Comment: I have the same result. But I (or somebody else) have to check your further calculations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I edited my work and adjusted for the standard deviation, I hope the rest is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is one-sided:  $$H_0 : \mu = \mu_0 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : \mu < \mu_0$$ where $\mu_0 = 1$ is the hypothesized mean.  The test statistic is $$T = \frac{\bar x - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}} \sim t_{n-1},$$ where $$\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0.938182$$ is the sample mean, $$s = \left(\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 \right)^{1/2} = 0.0475012$$ is the sample standard deviation, and $t_{n-1}$ is the Student $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.  $n = 11$ is the sample size.  The test statistic is $$T = -4.31626.$$ At a significance level of $\alpha = 0.05$, we reject $H_0$ if $T < -t_{n-1,\alpha}$ where $t_{n-1,\alpha}$ is the upper $100\alpha$ percentile of the Student $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.  In our case, we have $-t_{10,0.05} = -1.81246$, so our conclusion is to **reject** $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$:  the sample contains sufficient evidence to suggest with at least $95\%$ confidence that the mean weight of caviar is less than $1$ kilogram per container.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I now see that I should add more detail to my answer and perhaps keep more decimal places as well.